# Why does gcc's implementation of openMP fail to parallelise a recursive function inside another recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, gcc, openmp

I am trying to parallelise these recursive functions with openMP tasks,

when I compile with gcc it runs only on 1 thread. When i compile it with clang it runs on multiple threads

The second function calls the first one which doesn't generate new tasks to stop wasting time.

gcc does work when there is only one function that calls itself.

Why is this?

Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Then why does it work with clang?

I am using gcc 9.3 on windows with Msys2.
The code was compiled with -O3 -fopenmp

```
//the program compiled by gcc only runs on one thread
#include<vector>
#include<omp.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

vector<int> vec;
thread_local double steps;

void excalibur(int current_node, int current_depth) {
    #pragma omp simd
    for( int i = 0 ; i < current_node; i++){
        ++steps;
        excalibur(i, current_depth);
    }
    if(current_depth > 0){
        int new_depth = current_depth - 1;
        #pragma omp simd
        for(int i = current_node;i <= vec[current_node];i++){
            ++steps;
            excalibur(i + 1,new_depth);
        }
    } 
}

void mario( int current_node, int current_depth) {
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(current_node,current_depth)
    {
        if(current_depth > 0){
            int new_depth = current_depth - 1;
            for(int i = current_node;i <= vec[current_node];i++){
                ++steps;
                mario(i + 1,new_depth);
            }
        } 
    } 
    #pragma omp simd
    for( int i = 0 ; i < current_node; i++){
        ++steps;
        excalibur(i, current_depth);
    }
}



int main() {
    double total = 0;
    clock_t tim = clock();
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    int nodes = 10;
    int timesteps = 3;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    vec.assign( nodes, nodes - 2 );
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        steps = 0;
        #pragma omp single
        {
            mario(nodes - 1, timesteps - 1);
        }
        #pragma omp atomic
            total += steps;
    }
    double time_taken = (double)(tim) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout <<fixed<<total<<" steps, "<< fixed << time_taken << " seconds"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

while this works with gcc

```
#include<vector>
#include<omp.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

vector<int> vec;
thread_local double steps;

void mario( int current_node, int current_depth) {
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(current_node,current_depth)
    {
        if(current_depth > 0){
            int new_depth = current_depth - 1;
            for(int i = current_node;i <= vec[current_node];i++){
                ++steps;
                mario(i + 1,new_depth);
            }
        } 
    } 
    #pragma omp simd
    for( int i = 0 ; i < current_node; i++){
        ++steps;
        mario(i, current_depth);
    }
}



int main() {
    double total = 0;
    clock_t tim = clock();
    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    int nodes = 10;
    int timesteps = 3;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    vec.assign( nodes, nodes - 2 );
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        steps = 0;
        #pragma omp single
        {
            mario(nodes - 1, timesteps - 1);
        }
        #pragma omp atomic
            total += steps;
    }
    double time_taken = (double)(tim) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout <<fixed<<total<<" steps, "<< fixed << time_taken << " seconds"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are many unknowns here that could cause this behavior (eg. Is there a parallel section? Where are the scheduling points? How your OpenMP environment is configured? How many tasks are created? How long each task last? Which version of GCC/GOMP is used? Which compiler arguments are used? etc.).

Comment: Gcc is too shy about removing infinite loops with no side effects, compared to llvm :-(

Comment: @Marc Glisse can you tell me where the infinite loop is?

Comment: the recursion should end after a while

Comment: I might have phrased it wrong before, gcc does manage to compile the code but it only runs on one thread.

Comment: I think what @MarcGlisse is saying that GCC is more careful when it comes to unknown loop lengths. A recursive function could loop once or a large amount of times. It's likely that GCC has just chosen not to parallelize for recursive functions while other compilers trust that the programmer know what they are doing. Using parallel processing on recursive functions could have much worse performance depending on what you're doing.

Comment: unfortunately this algorithm could really benefit from parallel processing, I want to use gcc becuase I can't get clang to statically link everything, my .exe is always missing libomp.dll, I've tried -static, -static-openmp but none of them work

Comment: For me, clang optimizes the code to something that returns instantly (only at -O0 it actually takes time). I assumed that clang had somehow optimized the whole code to nothing, as it often does in benchmarks, and gcc hadn't, but I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: Did you use the CPU utilisation to determine if your code runs in parallel? If so, check out my updated answer as I may have the explanation.

Comment: In task manager I see cpu usage go up to 100 percent, which I assumed means that 4 threads have been created and run on my 4 core machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't run in parallel because there is simply nothing to run in parallel. Upon first entry in `mario`, `current_node` is `9` and `vec` is all `8`s, so this loop in the first and only task never executes:

```
        for(int i = current_node;i <= vec[current_node];i++){
            ++steps;
            mario(i + 1,new_depth);
        }
```

Hence, no recursive creation of new tasks. How and what runs in parallel when you compile it with Clang is well beyond me, since when I compile it with Clang 9, the executable behaves exactly the same as the one produced by GCC.

The second code runs in parallel because of the recursive call in the loop after the `task` region. But it also isn't a correct OpenMP program - the specification forbids nesting `task` regions inside a `simd` construct (see under **Restrictions** [here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu42.html)):

> - The only OpenMP constructs that can be encountered during execution of a `simd` region are the `atomic` construct, the `loop` construct, the `simd` construct and the `ordered` construct with the `simd` clause.

None of the two compilers catches that problem when the nesting is in the dynamic and not in the lexical scope of the `simd` construct though.

---

Edit: I actually looked it a bit closer into it and I may have a suspicion about what might have caused your confusion. I guess you determine if your program works in parallel or not by looking at the CPU utilisation while it runs. This often leads to confusion. The Intel OpenMP runtime that Clang uses has a very aggressive waiting policy. When the parallel region in the `main()` function spawns a team of four threads, one of them goes executing `mario()` and the other three hit the implicit barrier at the end of the region. There they spin, waiting for new tasks to be eventually assigned to them. They never get one, but keep on spinning anyway, and that's what you see in the CPU utilisation. If you want to replicate the same with GCC, set `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` to `ACTIVE` and you'll see the CPU usage soar while the program runs. Still, if you profile the program's execution, you'll see that CPU time is spent inside your code in one thread only.